# How to ban IPs trying to login as root with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have already blocked logging in as root with ssh, so I know that any attempt to do that is malicious. I know they wont succeed (sshd wont allow it), but I'd nevertheless would like to ban the IP in question immediately. How would I do that?

I'm running Gentoo Linux, and have fail2ban already running. I don't want to ban everyone for one failed logging attempt, so simply setting fail2ban attempt to 1 is not an option. Root is the only account I'd wish to apply this immediate ban.

Comment: Why would you do this? If root can't login, there's no benefit from blocking IPs that try.

Comment: @AlexHolst Those IPs are almost certainly part of Bot Nets, and though they may stop trying SSH, they might move on to a different attack vector. In any case once you've identified them, might as well perma-ban.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I setup two different Fail2Ban rules:

1. If they try an invalid username they get banned on the first try, permanently. I don't have many people getting in that way and none of them have ever got banned that way; but it may be a support issue if you've got lots of people signing in. Root isn't a valid ssh login on my systems.

   I'm on a FreeBSD system, so you might have to modify this rule a touch. Create a ssh-invaliduser.local file in the filter.d directory:

   ```
   failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\s*$
   ```

   Set the options for this rule as usual in the `jail.local` file.
2. The second rule locks out attempts that have got the password wrong 10 times for 10 minutes. Nobody's going to break in at 1 password per minute average speed.

Comment: I actually feel a bit dumb for not coming up with this myself. Two sets of rules, of course. Thank you, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard sshd log output and your system is running the tcp wrapper *tcpd*, try the following:

First add this line in */etc/hosts.deny*:

```
sshd: /tmp/root_ban.list
```

Then schedule cron to run the following command:

```
awk '/invalid user root from/{print $13}' /var/log/ssh_auth.log | sort -u > /tmp/root_ban.list
```

If the output of the awk part of the command doesn't work, ajust the condition part: *invalid user root from* to match your sshd logs. You might also need to change the field number captured by awk. I my logs, the ip is in the 13th position ($13).

And, to avoid blocking you out, you can add trusted ip's in the /etc/hosts.allow file:

```
sshd: 123.123.123.123 222.222.222.222
```

Comment: Setting up cron collection jobs when he's got Fail2Ban running seems awfully redundant.

Comment: Has anyone tried this?